# SQL query not returning expected amount of subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I've been trying variations of this SQL query:

```
SELECT
  c.Id
, c.Email
, c.RecordTypeId
, o.CreatedDate
, o.Name
, o.StageName as Stage
, ca.Subject
, ca.Status 
FROM Contact_Salesforce c
JOIN Opportunity_Salesforce o ON c.ID = o.agent__c
JOIN Case_Salesforce ca ON c.ID = ca.contactid
```

to join data from 3 separate synchronized DEs. When I filter the DEs on the fields I'm targeting I return records that are closer to expected but when I'm using the SQL I'm only returning a fraction of that amount.

I'm using the contact as my ID and sendable Email address and the opportunities and Case to filter further. Am I missing something? Any workarounds for combining 3 synced DEs and then filtering from there?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `JOIN` clause, it is using an `INNER JOIN` where it will only return records that have matching values in both synchronized data extensions.

When you filter a synchronized data extension, you are only filtering on one data extension without matching any values from any other data extension. This will return a larger record size.

In your case, you are only returning matching values from `Contact` and `Opportunity` on `ContactId = Agent__c` (which is a custom field in `Opportunity`). Also doing returning matching values on `Case` and `Contact` on `ContactId`.

It could be very possible that not all of your `Contacts` are in the `Opportunity` and `Case` objects.

See the diagram below on `JOIN` statements.

[image: JOIN statements]